# Cannot convert from table to class

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, visual-studio-2012

I am making an MVC 3 Article app and connecting it to a SQL database with LINQ. I'm trying to create a new article with LINQ code and I keep ending up with these errors:

> ArticleRepository.cs(41,13,41,47): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Linq.Table.InsertOnSubmit(NyjiGrunnur.ArticleTable)' has some invalid arguments
>
> ArticleRepository.cs(41,45,41,46): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'NyjiGrunnur.Models.Article' to 'NyjiGrunnur.ArticleTable'

Add article function:

```
public void AddArticle(Article s)
    {
        ArticleLINQDataContext db = new ArticleLINQDataContext();
        //Article a = new Article { Id = s.Id, Content = s.Content, Name = s.Name, Subject =        s.Subject, Created = (DateTime)s.Created };
    Line 41:    db.ArticleTables.InsertOnSubmit(s);
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

I have Articles.cs model:

```
namespace NyjiGrunnur.Models
{
    public class Article
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have LINQ to SQL classes that I'm working with. I also have a Edit function that works and is like this:

```
public void UpdateArticle(Article s)
    {
      ArticleLINQDataContext db = new ArticleLINQDataContext();

      var a = (from article in db.ArticleTables
                   where article.Id == s.Id
                   select article).SingleOrDefault();
      a.Name = s.Name;
      a.Subject = s.Subject;
      a.Content = s.Content;
      a.Created = s.Created;
      a.Id = s.Id;
      db.SubmitChanges();

    }
```

`HomeController` should also be working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error is trying to tell you, your LINQ to SQL classes use the `ArticleTable` class, which is not the same as the `Article` class.

You need to create an `ArticleTable` (data model) instance from the `Article` (view model) so that you can put it in the database.

Comment: I'm sorry if this seems stupid to ask, but how would I got about doing that? - Got it.

Comment: @Zanii: `new ArticleTable { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you were on track with AddArticle but commented out the mapping:

```
public void AddArticle(Article s)
{
    ArticleLINQDataContext db = new ArticleLINQDataContext();
    ArticleTable a = 
        new ArticleTable { 
                             Id = s.Id, // *see question below code sample
                             Content = s.Content, 
                             Name = s.Name, 
                             Subject = s.Subject, 
                             Created = (DateTime)s.Created 
                         };
    db.ArticleTables.InsertOnSubmit(a);   // <-- note it's "a" instead of "s"
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

*Is `Id` auto-generated?  If so you shouldn't be setting it when you insert it.