# How can I use List<string> in Linq to Entities as Entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a `List` of type `String` in which it has values with same name as properties in my Entity class,

For example,
I have `List<string>`

```
List<String> list = new List<String>(new String[]{ "Name", "Age", "Value" });
```

Now I have to query my table using `LinqtoEntities` using values in my list
like so:

```
db.Mytable.Where(z=>z.MyListValue1==SomeValue && z.MylistValue2==SomeValue &&
                    z.MyListValue3==SomeValue)
```

Is this possible? Or is there other workaround for doing like this?
because my `List<string>` values are same as my Class properties

I am using DB FIRST approach with EF5 ,Mvc5 and Oracle11g

Comment: Where are the values that you want to use?

Comment: In My List sachin

Comment: You can either have the names OR values in a List of string. I believe that "Name", "Age" and "Value" are the names of the properties and not the values.

Comment: Yes sachin "Name","Age" and "Value" are names of the properties

Comment: Do you have in place of SomeValue, ValueName, ValueAge, ... defined? From the example it seems that Name, Age, Value compared to the same value, but I think Name is string, Age is integer number.

Comment: They are just strings coming from other table with same name of properties in my table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Contains`:

```
db.Mytable.Where(z => list.Contains(z.YourPoperty))
```

Comment: Error : Cannot convert MyModel.Mytable to string

Comment: use any look in Linq

Comment: @MussaibSiddiqui Refer to this to solving this error http://stackoverflow.com/a/15364238/2946329

Comment: But i want to use property which are in list as type string, In your answer it is matching properties with my list,,,this list<string> can have different names as properties of my table

Comment: @MussaibSiddiqui The main point of the answer is using `Contain` method for this scenarios, you can change it depend on your requirements and different names.

Comment: In my table i have 20 to 25 properties and in my list there are 3 to 4 strings which are coming and i have to filter using these strings,, these strings can be different maybe different properties of table..so i have to use multiple linqtoEntities? thats what you mean?

Comment: @MussaibSiddiqui Well you can use the OR operator simply like this: `db.Mytable.Where(z => list.Contains(z.YourPoperty1) || list.Contains(z.YourPoperty2));` .

Comment: I think you guys are misunderstanding him. The list contains the property names, not the values. `Contains` does not work here.

Comment: @MussaibSiddiqui Also if you feel that `Contains` doesn't solve your issue you may have a look at [dynamiclinq](https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The list holds the propertynames you want to compare? Never did that before, so got no examples, but this how I would do it:

Dynamic linq is one way of doing it https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/

Another is doing some reflection yourself

And the last would be to try using `db.Entry()` and then the `Property()` method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry.property(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry.Property(System.String)

Comment: Ok Man I will try these,